# Mapping exception in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a big database for a multi lingual application that gets it's texts from the server , inserts into the database, then based on user preferred language, finds appropriate text.

Let me first describe the database then I'll say my problem:
[image]
Illustration: for example I have a table `Product`, which has a foreign key (`Description` column) to the `Translation` table which in turn connects to `TranslationEntry` table that has all the translations of products's description in all languages.

The languages are in a separate table called `Language` which has a foreign key to `TranslationEntry` table.

```
public class Product : BaseModel
{
    public int description { get; set; }
    public virtual Translation Description { get; set; }
}

public class Translation : BaseModel
{
    public Translation()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MainCategory> MainCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Caption> Captions { get; set; }
}

public class TranslationEntry : BaseModel
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int language { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public int translation { get; set; }
    public virtual Translation Translation { get; set; }
}

public class Language : BaseModel
{
    public Language()
    {
        TranslationEntries = new List<TranslationEntry>();
    }

    public string title { get; set; }
    public string language_code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TranslationEntry> TranslationEntries { get; set; }
}

public  class BaseModel
{
    public  int id { get; set; }
    public  int MembershipId { get; set; }
    public  SyncStatus SyncState { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Translation Entry Mapping:

```
        HasRequired(translationEntry => translationEntry.Translation)
            .WithMany(translation => translation.TranslationEntries)
            .HasForeignKey(translationEntry =>
                new {translationEntry.translation, translationEntry.MembershipId, translationEntry.SyncState})
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasRequired(translationEntry => translationEntry.Language)
            .WithMany(language => language.TranslationEntries)
            .HasForeignKey(translationEntry =>
                new {translationEntry.language, translationEntry.MembershipId, translationEntry.SyncState})
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        Property(t => t.translation)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_translatinlanguageOd", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
        Property(t => t.language)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_translatinlanguageOd", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
```

Product Mapping:

```
HasRequired(product => product.Description)
            .WithMany(translation => translation.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(product => new { product.description, product.MembershipId, product.SyncState })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Sample set of data here:

[image]

Now the problem: I want to get description of a product, I use the following command

```
var o = databaseContext.Products.ToList().First(p=>p.id==1)?.Description.TranslationEntries.First(te=>te.language==1);
```

but I get an error:

> A 'Mapping' exception occurred while processing the query. See the inner exception.
>
> Inner exception:
>   More than one property map found for property 'translation' when using case-insensitive search.

Note that there are many entities which have the same relationships for translation as `Product` table which I showed.

---

`UPDATE`: 
my temporary Solution is this:

```
var Language = context.Languages.Include(l => l.TranslationEntries)
                        .Where(l => l.id == languageId)
                        .ToList()
                        .FirstOrDefault();
TranslationEntries = Language?.TranslationEntries;
var translatedText = (from t in TranslationEntries where t.translation == 2 select t.text).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed this stupid problem!
As the error message says, the problem is by case-insensitive search there are 2 property named translation in `TranslationEntry` Class, I renamed one of them and now everything works without any problem!